# MediaPlayer when clicking on other buttons require 2 clicks to play

Tags: android, media-player, playback

I have MediaPlayer in GridView with `onItemClickListener` with cases.
I am using only 1 instance of MediaPlayer for all cases/files. But with the code that I have, this happens: I start mp on 1st button. And I want to play 2nd button. What happens, when I click on 2nd button MP stops and then I have to click again to play it.
Is there any way to avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
if (mPlay.isPlaying()) {
                        mPlay.reset();
                    } else {

                        mPlay = MediaPlayer
                                .create(ActivityM.this, R.raw.sound1);

                        mPlay.start();
                    }
```

Code is same for all Cases, the only difference is file.
I also tried with `mPlay.stop(); mPlay.Pause(); mPlay.seekTo(0);` etc but same thing happened.

Comment: How many sound files you have?

Comment: Only one way out used `Switch Case` for that and play sound file accordingly position

Comment: And for that do I need something like some method or? Or to create array of strings?

Comment: no not required any arrays. wait ill post my answer. try that

Comment: try as per my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `Switch Case` in your `onItemClickListener onItemClick(.....)` event like

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
switch(position){

    case 0:
     mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityM.this, R.raw.sound1);
     break;
    case 1:
     mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityM.this, R.raw.sound2);
     break;
    case 2:
    mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityM.this, R.raw.sound3);
     break;
    .... so on
    default:
 break; 
 }
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.